# Child elements multiply given parameters

Tags: css, wordpress

So i don't think that this problem is really complicated,its just that I am stupid.I want my sub-menu items to be smaller in size,this can be done by margin or padding,but the problem is there that my sub sub-menu is taking parameters x2 
lets say i give margin to parent 20px,the sub-sub menu will be with 40 px ;/
Here is picture of what i am talking about: [Click](http://prntscr.com/dap1uv)
Here is my CSS and HTMl

PS:I am working on wordpress and it is making my menu auto,i will try to represent it with HTML code,because in wordpress its PHP and you won't be able to see Ul's and Li's.

```css
.tablet-menu{
display:none;
background:#000;
position:fixed;
width:100%;
height:100%;
opacity:0.7;
z-index:1001;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.tablet-menu.show{
display:block;
}
.tablet-menu.hide{
display:none;
}
.tablet-menu ul{
position:relative;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
.tablet-menu li{
color:#FFF;
background:#000;
}
.tablet-menu li a{
text-transform: uppercase;
font-family: "Roboto Slab", Times, Georgia, serif;
font-weight:bold;
border-radius:2px;
border-bottom:1px solid white;
position:relative;
display:block;
padding-top:4%;
padding-bottom:4%;
}
.tablet-menu ul li ul{
display:none;
}
.tablet-menu li:hover *.sub-menu{
display:block;
margin-left:20px;
margin-right:20px;
}
.tablet-menu li:last-child{
border:none;
}
.tablet-menu li > a:after{
content: "\33";
font-family: "ElegantIcons";
}
.tablet-menu li a:only-child:after, .tablet-menu li li a:after{
content:"";
}
.tablet-menu li a:hover{
background:#fff;
color:#000;
}
```

```html
   <div class="tablet-menu">
      <ul class="tablet-menu-ul">
         <li><a>Front Page </a></li>
          <li><a>test1 </a></li>
           <ul class="sub-menu">
             <li><a>test2</a>
               <ul class="sub-menu">
                 <li><a></a>
                   </li>
               </ul>
             </li>
            </ul>
           <li><a>test3 </a></li>
           <li><a>test4 </a></li>
           <li><a>test5 </a></li>
         </ul>
     
     </div>
```

Comment: Could you update the question so the snippet represents something? As it is now (shows nothing) it's really hard to guess what could be wrong

Comment: You have to be more specific in your selectors and/or write a new rule for sub sub-menu.

Comment: Cannot be really more specific, i tried a lot combinations and classes,nothing work .